# Why a state, $|\Psi\rangle=c_A|\vec{x}_A\rangle+c_B|\vec{x}_B\rangle$, doesn't occur for macro but only for micro objects?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

Why are macroscopic objects, for example, a wine glass, never found in a superposition of a position eigenstate localized at $A$ and another localized at $B$? Why does it never exist in a state $|\Psi\rangle$: $$|\Psi\rangle=c_A|\vec{x}_A\rangle+c_B|\vec{x}_B\rangle, \quad c_A,c_B\in\mathbb{C}$$ where $|\vec{x}_A,|\vec{x}_B\rangle$ are two position eigenstates, localized at the points $A$ and $B$, respectively?

Comment: decoherence is the buzz word

Answer (score 2):

This is an open question in quantum mechanics: What are the mechanism that break-down quantum coherence and quantum super-positions?
There are many propose theories (e.g. continuous spontaneous localization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_spontaneous_localization_model)
but they are not experimentally verified yet.

How large can a superposition of atoms can be?
A quantum superposition has been created for roughly ~50cm for ultracold atoms (https://www.nature.com/articles/nature16155).

This is much larger than a glass of wine (at least the wine glasses I have at home).
However, these system require excellent control of the surroundings (vacuum system, magnetic shielding, manipulation with laser light).
I suppose everyone agrees that high temperatures and couplings to the environment destroys coherence.